# Why can't I define my variable with bracket notation in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been trying to define a variable with bracket notation just to get familiar with how it works and aren't getting any results.  Unfortunatelt I'm on on a tablet with a keyboard using Plunkr so I can't open the console and see what's going wrong, hopefully someone can spot the problem without needing an error message from the console.

my code inside the component class currently looks like this

```
var  demoA:string='name';
var  demoB:string='city';
var  demoD:string='';
var  demoC:{[propName: string]:string}= {};

demoC['demoA']= demoD;
```

seing that I'm using typescript I didn't originally have `var` at the beginning of the variables but I eventually decided to set it up as it was on the MDN site and still didn't get any results, the widget just stays stck on loading.  I also tried adding `this.` to everything in the attempt to create the new property.  My goal is to have `demoC` with a property of `name=''` inside of it.  What am I missing here?

Here's my entire file on plunker

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <p>{{demoA}}</p>
    <p>{{demoB}}</p>
    <br />
    <p>{{demoC}}</p>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;

  var  demoA:string='name';
  var  demoB:string='city';
  var  demoD:string='';
  var  demoC:{[propName: string]:string}= {};

  demoC[demoA]= demoD;

  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used the `string` with name `demoA`, not the variables value. It will create a property with name `demoA`. Remove the `''` from the `[]` notation to let the `[]` syntax to evaluate the expression and get the value from it.

```
demoC[demoA]= demoD;
```

This is the example in [**TypeScript playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=var%20%20demoA%3Astring%3D'name'%3B%0D%0Avar%20%20demoB%3Astring%3D'city'%3B%0D%0Avar%20%20demoD%3Astring%3D''%3B%0D%0Avar%20%20demoC%3A%7B%5BpropName%3A%20string%5D%3Astring%7D%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AdemoC%5BdemoA%5D%20%3D%20demoD%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(demoC))

According to your Plunker code, you have some errors

Remove the `var` parts from the variables declarations.
Put the assignment operator of the `demoC` into your `constructor`. It understands your statement as a duplicate variable.

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <p>{{demoA}}</p>
    <p>{{demoB}}</p>
    <br />
    <p>{{demoC}}</p>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name: string;

  demoA: string = 'name';
  demoB: string = 'city';
  demoD: string = '';
  demoC: { [propName: string]: string} = {};

  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;
    this.demoC[this.demoA]= this.demoD;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Code example

**[Plunker code example](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview)**

Comment: I tried that as well, just tried it again.  The widget is still stuck saying `loading...`.

Comment: This is working code part. There may be something on your side. With your approach you make a property with name `demoA`, with this you create with the `name`. Try to open with PC

Comment: I  just updated my question to have the plunker code.

Comment: @Optiq Edited .

Comment: ok I'm still getting same error. And that's odd because the example they gave showed it all in a row, didn't know it needed to go in the constructor.  I even tried adding `this.` to it seeing that it needs to call `this.Name`, still have `loading...`

Comment: This line needed `this.demoC[this.demoA]= this.demoD`.

Comment: See the plunker link at the last line. It is working !

Comment: YESSSS THAT WORKS!!! thanks.  Now if I wanted to dynamically bind an ngModel to that on an input I could do so by doing `[(ngModel)] = "demoC[demoA]"` and that would result the same as `demoC.name` right?

Comment: @Optiq Yes it will. Lets remove comments